# Swift 3 extension returning "has no member" error

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, extension-methods

I created an extension called *UnderlinedUITextField*. I'm trying to call it's sole function, *underlined* on a UITextField in another class, but I get an error **Value of type 'UITextField' has no member 'underlined.'**

I followed an example I found online and it works perfectly for them. I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.

**UnderlinedUITextField extension**

```
import UIKit

extension UnderlinedUITextField {

func underlined() {

    let border = CALayer()
    let width = CGFloat(1.0)
    border.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.size.height - width, width:  self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height)
    border.borderWidth = width
    self.layer.addSublayer(border)
    self.layer.masksToBounds = true
}
}
```

**HomeScreenVC**

```
import UIKit

class HomeScreenVC: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    titleOfArticleTextField.underlined() <- WHERE I GET THE ERROR MESSAGE

}

//MARK: Properties

@IBOutlet weak var titleOfArticleTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var authorTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var bulletPointTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var previewOfImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var uploadImage: UIButton!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your extension should be to `UITextField` not of `UnderlinedUITextField`  You want to extend the existing class to have a new method.

Answer (score 0):

Your `titleOfArticleTextField` is a normal `UITextField` so it does not know that you have added a function called `underlined` to `UnderlinedUITextField`

Try changing your extension so it it extends `UITextField` instead:

```
extension UITextField {

    func underlined() {
        let border = CALayer()
        let width = CGFloat(1.0)
        border.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.size.height - width, width:  self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height)
        border.borderWidth = width
        self.layer.addSublayer(border)
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `UnderlinedUITextField` is the control extended using `UITextField`, so my guess is that the type of variable `titleOfArticleTextField` should be `UnderlinedUITextField` instead of `UITextField`:

```
@IBOutlet weak var titleOfArticleTextField: UnderlinedUITextField!  // <-- Check type here
```

this should fix the error, and find the method.

Since your extension is defined for `UnderlinedUITextField`, using this way you are safe to call the underline function to only textfields that are of type `UnderlinedUITextField` and it won't be available for type `UITextField` type.

Answer (score 0):

your extension name must be **UITextField**.

Because extension as the name says it extends the functionality of that particular class. Now if you want to add some more functionality for UITextField class then you have to create an extension with name UITextField.